# Submit not triggered on enter the text box after filling the value. in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have a form, In this form there is only one text field. after the field is filled user pressing enter key. but the form is not submit in `ie8` how to fix this.

But it works fine with chrome and firefox.

example code :

```
<form>
    <label><input type="text" /></label>
    <input value="Enter after adding value" type="submit">
</form>
```

how to make `ie` to work on enter key pressed.

thanks in advance!

Comment: check this out: http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/submit-a-form-in-ie-with-enter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browsers by default allow the enter key to submit a form, others do not.

You can work around this by adding an event handler that will submit the form on enter key.  Try something like

```
$("input").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("form").submit();
    }
});
```

If you have multiple forms on the page, then ensure you add an id attribute and update the above code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There you go

```
<form id="myForm">
<label><input type="text" /></label>
<input value="Enter after adding value" type="submit" id="name">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{

$("#name").keypress(function(e)
  {
  if(e.which==13){
  document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
  }
  });
  });
```

I hope that I could help